# PicoCLI ignoring dollar sign in a given string

Tags: java, picocli

I am using picocli as a utility to encrypt a given password. In my CLI, I have the option to pass the password String, and a key file. The key file will be used to encrypt the password string.

When the password string is containing a dollar ($) sign, picocli is ignoring it.

For example,

`java -jar encryption.jar passwd-enc -password "test23$34" -key /user/local/key.txt.`

The password parsed by *java* is **"test234"** instead of **"test23$34"**.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's almost certainly a matter of your shell's handling of the command line argument rather than anything to do with Java or picocli. You can validate that by just echoing the command line argument:

```bash
$ echo "test23$34"
test234
```

Assuming something like bash, either use single quotes around the password to prevent variable substitution: `'test23$34'` or escape the dollar with a backslash: `"test23\$34"`.